# Java: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit

SOLVED! Check the answers below

I am working with the GitHub repo, want to access the names of the users' repos. The JSON looks like this:

```
 [
      {
         "id": 55848012,
          "name": "Android",
          "full_name": "VyaraGGeorgieva/Android"
          ...
          ...
}
]
```

I have a Repo class

```
public class Repo {

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

And a class, storing the returned query:

```
public class GitHubRepos {

private Repo[] repos;

public Repo[] getRepos() {
    return repos;
}

public void setRepos(Repo[] repos) {
    this.repos = repos;
}
```

The endPoint is defines as this:

```
 @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
Call<List<GitHubRepos>> getRepoName(@Path("user") String name);
```

When I try to execute the calling:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GitHubRepos>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<GitHubRepos>> call, Response<List<GitHubRepos>> response) {
            Repo[] repos = response.body().**getRepos()**;
            Log.d("Repos: ", "Number of repos received: " + repos.length);
        }
```

Defined on this way, I can't access the getRepos() method.

I don't define correctly some types, but not sure how to fix the problem.

Comment: use this to create models http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass List instead of Object.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GitHubRepos>>() {
        //override method.
    });
```

Comment: What about the declaration within the GitHubRepo class? As it is, or a list of repos again?

Comment: as it is.

but you need to modify your interface method, where you defined url parameter.

Comment: I tried to modify it like this, but still no success   @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
    Call<List<GitHubRepos>> getRepoName(@Path("user") String name);

Comment: Please, check the code as it is now, I've just updated it.